# Dart - how can i toggle core drawer panel?

Tags: html, dart, polymer, dart-polymer, dart-html

I'm trying to toggle drawer panel in Dart, but it throws `type 'HtmlElement' is not a subtype of type 'CoreDrawerPanel' of 'panel'.` on line `CoreDrawerPanel panel = querySelector('#drawerPanel');`

Here is my dart:

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:core_elements/core_drawer_panel.dart';

void main() {
  querySelector('#navicon')
    ..onClick.listen(naviconClick);
}

void naviconClick(Event event) {
  CoreDrawerPanel panel = querySelector('#drawerPanel');
  panel.togglePanel();
}
```

And here is my HTML:

```
    <core-drawer-panel id="drawerPanel">
      <core-header-panel drawer>
        <core-toolbar>Menu</core-toolbar>
        <core-menu>
          <core-item label="One"></core-item>
          <core-item label="Two"></core-item>
        </core-menu>
      </core-header-panel>
      <core-header-panel main>
        <core-toolbar>
          <core-icon-button id="navicon" icon="menu"></core-icon-button>
          <div>Project</div>
        </core-toolbar>
        <div class="content">
        </div>
      </core-header-panel>
    </core-drawer-panel>
```

Thanks for answers.

Comment: What's the exact error thrown?

Comment: type 'HtmlElement' is not a subtype of type 'CoreDrawerPanel' of 'panel'. this error it throws

Comment: If you have a custom `main()` method you need to ensure Polymer initialization is done before accessing Polymer elements content.

Comment: when i'm trying init polymer( initPolymer().run(() {...)  DartEditor throws warning The method 'run' is not defined for the class 'Future<Zone>' , and i have imported polymer package

Comment: The answer to my referenced question contains 3 different ways to initialize Polymer in a custom main. Your Polymer version probably requires the 1st or 2nd way but you used the 3rd. Try renaming `main` to something else and add `@whenPolymerReady` as shown in my answer.